# How to access image histogram values in python-fu?

Tags: gimp, python

I have been writing code in the python-fu console of gimp and I wanted to find the minimum of an image histogram (the pixel intensity value with the least frequency).

There are two functions in the procedural database that deals with histograms - `pdb.gimp_drawable_histogram()` and `pdb.python_fu_histogram_export()`. The first function `pdb.gimp_drawable_histogram()` is not useful for me because it does not give me the histogram minimum. The second function `pdb.python_fu_histogram_export()` does exactly what I want, but it exports the result into a .csv file and prevents me from accessing the values within the console.

I can get around this by exporting the .csv function first, followed by importing the .csv file back into the console and accessing the values. But this seems like a rather ugly and inefficient way to do it.

Is there a way to access the histogram values without exporting it to a .csv and then back into the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `gimp_drawable_histogram` while iterating a window, for instance:

```
hist=[pdb.gimp_drawable_histogram(drawable,HISTOGRAM_VALUE,x/255.,(x+1)/255.) for x in range(255)]
```

On an 8Mpix image it takes a couple of seconds. If you don't need that much precision you can use wider windows to make it run faster.

PS: it turns out that the CSV export you mention, written in Python, does exactly that (so won't run any faster). You can find it in your Gimp installation, as `lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/histogram-export/histogram-export.py`, under `/usr` in a regular Linux install, or your Gimp install tree in Windows.